# laravel routing like code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel

Im trying to switch from using code igniter to laravel however I noticed in every tutorial I'd followed, we always declare the route in route.php in laravel unlike in code igniter that it has a default routing like `http://localhost/projname/controller/method`. Is there a way to have an auto routing like CI or I'd just missed something in laravel routing rules?This is very important because we all know big websites have more than 50 links and it will be a hustle if we are going to declare those all in routes.php in laravel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a way to have an auto routing like CI

Why yes there is. In your route file do `Route::controller(Controller::detect());`

Now in your controller class make sure each function name is concatenated with `action_`. So if your function name is `homepage()` then make it `action_homepage()`

Keep in mind that you can use restful controller names `get_homepage()` and `post_homepage()`. But you'll have to declare this class variable in your controller `public static $restful = true;`

Comment: Route::controller(Controller::detect()); This function has been removed in Laravel 4 because of inconsistent behavior with varying filesystems. The proper way to register controllers should be to explicitly define each one you wish to use in your routes file.

Comment: Laravel 5 has again `Route::controller()` option. http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#implicit-controllers

Answer (score 0):

```
    //create controller name like UserController

//Steps:
// 1. route matched to either post or get request, 
// 2. used web/controllerName/MethodName/Parameter1/parameter2 .. 
// all parameters received in an array as $params. web/ is used like a route 
// prefix. If no method is passed it will call index method
// 3. explode the parameter
// 4. called the controller with method and paramteres passed
// 5. parameters are matched for regex allowing alphanumeric and slash (url)
// 6. passed through guest middleware

// created controller as mentioned below:

// class SomeController extends Controller
// {
//     public function index($param1,$param2,$param3){

//       return 'index'.$param1.$param2.$param3;
//     }


// }



Route::match(['get','post'],'/web/{controller}/{method?}/{params?}', function ($controller, $method='index', $params='') {    

    $params = explode('/', $params);

    $controller = app()->make("\App\Http\Controllers\\". ucwords($controller).'Controller' );


    return $controller->callAction($method, $params);

})->where('params', '[A-Za-z0-9/]+')->middleware('guest');
```

Comment: Can you share some more context such that the OP can learn why you do what in your code?